# ARRAYFORMULA && Extract Num From String

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to use an arrayformula on google sheets to auto-populate a column which will extract the number from a string. I've found / made multiple methods of extracting the number from the string, but I can't seem to get it to work in an arrayformula.

This formula works perfectly to extract the text, but because it's creating an array it's not working within the array formula.

`TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR((MID(H13,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(H13))),1)*1),""))`

This below just won't work. I've tried multiple methods, but can't get it working. Clearly I'm making a circular reference, but I can't see to solve it.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(C12:C)=12, "Num", IF(ISBLANK(C12:C), "", TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR((MID(H13:H,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(H13:H))),1)*1),"")))))`

Included is an example worksheet, with a column with expected output.

Thanks for your time! :)

[Example Worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1myQ515rPxIy_BUzuyTwkxwmPzrguJ_64bAdyWbL4tBs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Not sure what you want. In your data you have the expected result where you have an array formula. What is wrong with that formula?

Answer (score 1):

What you could try, as I demonstrated in `M13` on your sheet, is to use `REGEXREPLACE()` to remove anything from your data that is **not** a digit through "\D":

```
=INDEX(IF(H13:H="","",REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(H13:H,"@"),"\D","")))
```

Comment: ```=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW($C12:$C)=12, "Array Attempt 4", IF(ISBLANK($C12:$C), "",INDEX(IF(I12:I="","",REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(I12:I,"@"),"\D","")))       )))```

I love you. Miracle worker! <3